# DELPHI STRING: Pull a last name from a full name

Tags: delphi, string, delphi-2009

I am trying to manipulate a string and pull only certain data from it. I need to do this on a record pulled from a database that gives me the full name of a person. I need to pull only the last name from the string and store it as a variable. Is there a way that I can do this?

Example: SQL query pulls the full field "Mary Ellen Jones" I need to extract only the Jones from the string so I can store it in a variable for further processing.

I thought maybe AnsiRightStr would work but the problem is needing to give it a set integer to pull from the right. Maybe a way to count the characters after the final space allowing me to use AnsiRightStr(string,int) for this? Any help at all is appreciated.

Additional thought: Would replacing the spaces with a delimiter say :: and then parsing that data into a Stringlist followed by allowing me to pull the last index of the string list be possible?

Several valid options have been presented so far. None of them address the situation if say the name is Something like "John St. James, Jr." Is this impossible?

Comment: You can split a string on spaces too when you use a stringlist. But there is no way of telling whether the last name consists only of the last word. I you want to solve this correctly, save the first name and last name in separate fields in the database. That allows for better sorting and searching possibilities too.

Comment: As long as your names are fairly Anglocentric, with a "First Middle Last" pattern, breaking on spaces should work.  What about people with 4 words to their name?  Is it 2 "middle" names or 2 "last" names, or an unhyphenated double last name?  Names are *hard* to deal with and parse in all situations.

Comment: @afraizer: I am seeing this as this question and answers evolve.

Comment: @Golez: The issue that I work for a company that writes Bankruptcy software, in the past codebtors only needed to be noted in a few places. The company chose to list the fullname of the codebtor into a single record while the debtor got split records. Now that the courts are pushing more secure data we find the need to redact codebtor first and middle names. Changing it now is not feasible for what we need done.

Comment: @JamesW: Dive down the rabbit hole of this question far enough and you'll realize that the only *real* solution is to fix your DB and data-entry practices to use separate fields, the contents of which may not even be immediately apparent.  (e.g., using "Full Name" and "Salutation" fields for storing "Mary Ellen Jones" and "Ms. Jones", rather than "First/Middle/Last" name fields.)  You can probably special case enough suffixes and last name joiners to either work for your current dataset or make migration to a new schema less painful.

Comment: Of course, it is not possible in the general case on non-sanitized input data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What if the last name is say "St. James" any way to account for that?

Here's my approach.

1. Make a list of lastname-markers
2. Search that list in order of preference
3. As soon as a match is found, mark that as the start of last name
4. Return substring starting from that pos.

```
var
  LastNameMarkers: TStringList = nil;
  SuffixFix: TStringList = nil;
```

```
procedure InitLists;
begin
  LastNameMarkers:= TStringList.Create;
  //LastNameMarkers.LoadFromFile('c:\markers.txt');
  LastNameMarkers.Add(' St.');
  LastnameMarkers.Add(' Mc');
  LastNameMarkers.Add(' '); //Marker of last resort.
  SuffixFix:= TStringList.Create;
  SuffixFix.Add(' Jr.');
  SuffixFix.Add(' Sr.');
end;

function GetLastName(FullName: string): string;
var
  i: integer;
  start: integer;
  found: boolean;
  ReplaceWith: string;
begin
  if LastNameMarkers = nil then InitLists;

  //Fix suffixes
  i:= 0;
  found:= false;
  while (i < SuffixFix.Count) and not found do begin
    start:= pos(lower(LastNameMarkers[i]),lower(Fullname));
    found:= Start > 0;
    Inc(i);
  end; {while}
  if Found then begin 
    Dec(i);
    ReplaceWith:= StringReplace(Suffix[i], ' ', '_',[]);
    FullName:= StringReplace(FullName, SuffixFix[i], ReplaceWith,[]);
  end; {if}

  //Look for lastnames 
  i:= 0;
  found:= false;
  while (i < LastNameMarkers.Count) and not found do begin
    start:= pos(LastNameMarkers[i],Fullname);
    found:= Start > 0;
    Inc(i);
  end; {while}

  if found then Result:= RightStr(FullName, Length(FullName)- Start + 2)
  else Result:= '';

  StringReplace(Result, '_', ' ',[]);
end;
```

I haven't dealt with upper and lowercase properly, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: ReplaceWith:= StringReplace(Suffix[i], ' ', '_',[]); is kicking up an index out of bounds error.

Comment: While I didn't end up using this exact code I used a very similar thing. I will post it as an answer to this question for review. It actually incorporates this logic (kinda) with the Get last word of Andreas' answer.

Comment: This answer is still very anglo-centric.  I wouldn't trust such a system in a real world database system.

Comment: @warren, of course not it's a desperate hack to salvage a borken db design. No way would I recommend this. I remember reading Knuth's paper on this, his conclusion this problem has no solution. The only reason humans can do this is because they use a massive database advanced pattern matching and heuristics

Comment: Even humans would make a mistake. And then there is the complication that family names come first in some cultures, and the individual's own name is last.  So even "first name" is an ethocentrism.

Answer (score 7):

you can use the [`LastDelimiter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.LastDelimiter) function to get the last space position and then with the [`copy`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Copy) function extract the substring.

```
uses
  SysUtils;


var
  Name      : string;
  p         : Integer;
  ShortName : string;
begin
  Name:='Mary Ellen Jones';
  //You can call trim to avoid problems with ending spaces in this case is not necesary, just is a test
  //Name:=Trim(Name); 
  //get the last space position
  p:=LastDelimiter(' ',Name);
  //get the name
  ShortName:=Copy(Name,p+1,length(Name)-p);
end;
```

or using a function

```
function GetLast(const Name:string) : string;
var
  p : Integer;
begin
  Result:=Trim(Name);
  p:=LastDelimiter(' ',Result);
  Result:=Copy(Result,p+1,length(Result)-p);
end;
```

Comment: Your way seems to be also very valid way to do what I need to do. Any way to handle the situation mentioned in comments to Andreas answer to account for Prefixes and suffixes, as in the case of the name being "Bobby St Jones, Jr."

Comment: @JamesW, these cases can be handled building a more complex function, but before you must define the scope of that, adding all the prefixes like `St`.

Comment: @JamesW: The only was is to hardcode the most common prefixes, or use some heuristics to guess if a 'word' is a title or suffix or not. It wouldn't be too hard to do that, but it will probably never work to 100 % and it requires some thought.

Answer (score 6):

```
function GetLastWord(const Str: string): string;
var
  p: integer;
  i: Integer;
const
  SPACE = #$20;
begin
  p := 1;
  for i := length(Str) downto 1 do
    if Str[i] = SPACE then
    begin
      p := i + 1;
      break;
    end;
  result := Copy(Str, p, MaxInt);
end;
```

This will fail if the string ends with (an accidental) space, as 'Andreas Rejbrand '. This more robust version will handle this case too:

```
function GetLastWord(const Str: string): string;
var
  p: integer;
  i: Integer;
  FoundNonSpace: boolean;
const
  SPACE = #$20;
begin
  p := 1;
  FoundNonSpace := false;
  for i := length(Str) downto 1 do
    if (Str[i] = SPACE) and FoundNonSpace then
    begin
      p := i + 1;
      break
    end
    else if Str[i] <> SPACE then
      FoundNonSpace := true;
  result := TrimRight(Copy(Str, p, MaxInt));
end;
```

Comment: I was just about to post that!  :-P

Comment: Awesome, thank you. This is exactly what I needed. I will accept the answer in a couple of minutes when SO will allow me to.

Comment: @JamesW, hurry or Andreas will run away :-).

Comment: One question though. What if the last name is say "St. James" any way to account for that?

Comment: @JamesW, seriously, you should take your time accepting an answer, someone might come up with something even more brilliant.

Comment: @James: That is hard. What if the last name contains a "prefix" without an explicit period? That's very hard.

Comment: @Andreas: I could see how that would be difficult, I also see where things like Jr., Sr. III etc could cause an issue as well

Comment: @Johan: After discussing the difficulty here in these comments. You are correct. I will give it some time before I choose the best answer.

Comment: While this was used in my solution, Johan's thinking helped me get the answer that worked.

Comment: This really helped me out thanks Andreas. +1 for very good answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
function TfrmCal.GetLastName(FullName: string): string;
var
    i: integer;
    found: boolean;
    suffix: string;
    marker: string;
begin
    // Build the lists for the compare.
    InitLists;

    // Look at Suffixes and attach them to the LastName
    i := 0;
    found := False;
    while (i < SuffixFix.Count) do
    begin
        if AnsiContainsStr(FullName, SuffixFix[i]) then
        begin
            suffix := '::' + trim(SuffixFix[i]);
            FullName := ReplaceStr(FullName, SuffixFix[i], suffix);
            found := True;
        end;
        inc(i);
        if found then
            break;
    end;
    // Look for LastName Markers
    i := 0;
    found := False;
    while (i < LastNameMarkers.Count) do
    begin
        if AnsiContainsStr(FullName, LastNameMarkers[i]) then
        begin
            marker := trimright(LastNameMarkers[i]) + '::';
            FullName := ReplaceStr(FullName, LastNameMarkers[i], marker);
            found := True;
        end;
        inc(i);
        if found then
            break;
    end;

    FullName := GetLastWord(FullName);
    FullName := ReplaceStr(FullName, '::', ' ');
    LastNameMarkers.Clear;
    SuffixFix.Clear;
    Result := FullName;
end;

function TfrmCal.GetLastWord(const Str: string): string;
var
    p: integer;
    i: integer;
const
    SPACE = #$20;
begin
    p := 1;
    for i := Length(Str) downto 1 do
        if Str[i] = SPACE then
        begin
            p := i + 1;
            break;
        end;
    Result := Copy(Str, p, MaxInt);
end;
```

These two functions together pull off what I needed to do. There is also the initlists function which is clunky and ugly and I need to work on so I didn't post it here.

Comment: you failed to account for upper/lower case. Other than that this looks OK. Id use `if AnsiContainsStr(lower(FullName), lower(SuffixFix[i])) then ...` to make the comparison case insensitive

Comment: I may look at that option, the lowers are accounted for, it's just done in the TStringlist and the ugly code that I didn't show here.